# cakephp path to root for javascript

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I need to create a javascript variable with the path to the css folder in the webroot for a jQuery WYSIWYG plugin which references a css.

My code into the head in the layout file

```
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock(sprintf('var WEBROOT_PATH = "%s";', WWW_ROOT));
```

bootstrap3-wysihtml5.js

```
var defaultOptions = $.fn.wysihtml5.defaultOptions = {
    "link": true,
    "image": true,
    "size": 'sm',
    events: {},
    parserRules: {
        classes: {
            "wysiwyg-color-silver" : 1,
        },
        tags: {
            "b":  {},
            "i":  {},
            "blockquote": {},
            "u": 1,
            "img": {
                "check_attributes": {
                    "width": "numbers",
                    "alt": "alt",
                    "src": "url",
                    "height": "numbers"
                }
            },
            "span": 1,
        }
    },
    stylesheets: [WEBROOT_PATH+"css/bootstrap3-wysiwyg5-color.css"],
    locale: "en"
};
```

I have tried all the cakephp constants and they all lead to the absolute path

```
http://localhost:8888/Users/keithpower/Documents/Website%20Projects/btstadmin/app/webroot/css/bootstrap3-wysiwyg5-color.css
```

**the path I need is**

```
 http://localhost:8888/btstadmin/app/webroot/css/bootstrap3-wysiwyg5-color.css
```

I have also tried

```
stylesheets: ["/css/bootstrap3-wysiwyg5-color.css"],
```

and I get

```
http://localhost:8888/css/bootstrap3-wysiwyg5-color.css
```

Comment: I have had success with `<script>var base_url = '<?php echo Router::url('/'); ?>';</script>` when passing the path to JS files. `[base_url + "css/bootstrap3..."]` should work nicely.

Comment: Great thanks, that has work perfectly. Add this as an answer and I will make it as correct.